# ModuleNotFoundError after successful package installation

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to install and use new Python packages e.g. `mysql`:

```
pip install mysql
Collecting mysqlNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  Using cached mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (180 kB)

Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, mysql
Successfully installed mysql-0.0.3 mysqlclient-2.1.0
```

However, if I run the code I receive the following error:

```
runfile('untitled1.py', wdir='')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "untitled1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Also restarting the Kernel does not solve the problem:

```
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.29.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Restarting kernel...
```

I am using Spyder 5.0.0 on a fresh Anaconda 2.0.3 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not familiar with Anaconda, although from a quick search I don't think that should change anything about my answer.

From the PyPI description for mysql:

> This package is a ‘virtual package’, which requires MySQL-python
> (Python 2) or mysqlclient (Python 3) to install. In effect, this means
> ‘pip install mysql’ will actually install MySQL-python.

Since you're on Python 3, what it installs is mysqlclient. This is confirmed by the pip output `Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, mysql`. From the [docs](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/) for that package, you can see that you have to import `MySQLdb` rather than `mysql`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I feel stupid. At least the problem does not seem to be as severe as I thought and should not apply to other packages as well. Thanks!